# Use of constructor and class JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, oop

I'm working on code with the following instructions:

Create a class called ShoppingCart.

Create a constructor that has no arguments and sets the total attribute to zero, and initializes an empty dict attribute named items.

Create a method add_item that requires item_name, quantity and price arguments. This method should add the cost of the added items to the current value of total. It should also add an entry to the items dict such that the key is the item_name and the value is the quantity of the item.

Create a method remove_item that requires similar arguments as add_item. It should remove items that have been added to the shopping cart and are not required. This method should deduct the cost of these items from the current total and also update the items dict accordingly. If the quantity of items to be removed exceeds current quantity in cart, assume that all entries of that item are to be removed.

Create a method checkout that takes in cash_paid and returns the value of balance from the payment. If cash_paid is not enough to cover the total, return Cash paid not enough.

Create a class called Shop that has a constructor which initializes an attribute called quantity at 100.

Make sure Shop inherits from ShoppingCart.

In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by one.

JavaScript
Use camel case for your class method names, such that

```
add_item
```

becomes

```
addItem
```

The only problem, is that my code, seen below, is not doing the trick:

```
function ShoppingCart(){
  this.total = 0;
  this.items = {};
  this.addItem = function(itemName, quantity, price){
    this.total = this.total + price;
    this.items[itemName] = quantity;
    //console.log(this.items);
  }
  this.removeItem = function(itemName, quantity, price){
    delete this.items['Mango'];
    // this.total = this.total - price;
    if (quantity > Object.keys(this.items).length){
      this.items = {};
    }
    //console.log(price);
    //console.log(this.total);
  }
  this.checkout = function(cashPaid){
    if (cashPaid >= this.total){
      return cashPaid - this.total;
    }
    return 'Cash paid not enough';
  }
}

class Shop extends ShoppingCart {
  constructor(quantity){
    super(quantity);
    this.quantity = 100;
  }
  removeItem(){
    this.quantity--;
  }
}
```

Can you please help write a code that fulfils all the conditions?

I'm pretty sure my code is a mess, as I'm new to OOP in JS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you create a function ShoppingCart? Isn't the requirement to create a class, like you did for Shop?

Comment: @baao I created a constructor. Should the constructor itself be a class?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? _Is not doing the trick_ doesn't help me very much...

Comment: When you say "My code is not doing the trick", could you be more specific? What is it doing now, and what did you expect it to do? Share error messages as well, if any

Comment: The first sentence of your requirement is _Create a class called ShoppinCart_

Answer (score 2):

You should transform `ShoppingCart` into a class too, after this it works:

```js
class ShoppingCart {
  constructor() {
    this.total = 0;
    this.items = {};
  }
  addItem(itemName, quantity, price){
    this.total = this.total + price;
    this.items[itemName] = quantity;
    //console.log(this.items);
  }
  removeItem(itemName, quantity, price){
    delete this.items['Mango'];
    // this.total = this.total - price;
    if (quantity > Object.keys(this.items).length){
      this.items = {};
    }
    //console.log(price);
    //console.log(this.total);
  }
  checkout(cashPaid){
    if (cashPaid >= this.total){
      return cashPaid - this.total;
    }
    return 'Cash paid not enough';
  }
}

class Shop extends ShoppingCart {
  constructor(quantity){
    super(quantity);
    this.quantity = 100;
  }
  removeItem(){
    this.quantity--;
  }
}

console.log(new Shop().removeItem)
```

Comment: It does, look at the console output when you run my example

Comment: please help check the checkout function.

Comment: I know. Please can you write it to your own taste, fulfilling all the given conditions? Please.

Comment: No. It's your assignment, I helped solve this problem, not gonna help you cheat your homework ;-)

Comment: @OluwakoredeFashokun see https://github.com/dessHub/dessHub.github.io/wiki/ShoppingCart